# C# windows application on xml schema viewer

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xsd

I am very new to windows application development. I was planning to develop an application that will take an xml schema file and create a tree view control.

Can some one guide me what articles to read and how to architect the software in C#? I know that this is an irrevelant question, but still expect some help.

(I have the 2008 version).

Comment: First guidance: say what kind of application this is: Windows Forms? ASP.NET, or what?

Comment: It is a windows form (EXE) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new, I would suggest to start working on two fronts: how XSD is supported on the .NET platform, particularly the [System.Xml.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.aspx) package, and how to play around with Winform controls.

To begin with, XSD is just XML. Simple XSD, would be particularly easy to start with. Binding an XML file to a tree view control, is something that's probably beaten to death. Take a look at Codeproject, maybe start with this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13099/Loading-and-Saving-a-TreeView-control-to-an-XML-fi). Knowing XSD, maybe the XSD API I was referring above, will help you understand what is it you want to see in the tree, and what's the best method of expression based on your need. For e.g., how do you want to organize the nodes? how do you want to parse the XSD files? as XML or as compiled and valid XSD files? Do you want to display the layout as it was authored in the source, or showing the post compilation infoset?

Maybe you can take a look at existing software that does it already. For example, [QTAssistant XSR](http://paschidev.com) has different views of XSD content, using trees.

[image: QTAssistant tree view for XSD content in filters]

If you're familiar with XSD, you may know the answers already. Otherwise, learn enough XSD to answer the above yourself, as it'll drive your design. Good luck!